# Javascript to click button

Tags: javascript, html

Below i have a html code

```
<td valign="top" id="UserManagebutton1"><input type="button" value="Add" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" value="Import" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" value="Export" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" value="Change Status" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" value="Purge AD Users" class="inputbutton"></td>
```

I tried putting this into my console but it did not work. I am trying to click the Add Button.

Below is the code i used.

`document.getElementById('Add').click();`

Any idea why its not working? It works with others.

Comment: the button value is 'Add' but not its id and you are using `getElementbyId()` to fetch it

Comment: Ah so which element would be for value?

Comment: You should have specified in the question that you do not have control of the page you are attempting to manipulate. How are you loading code onto the page? Regardless, my answer should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Through the console now then ill have someone here write a script to automate something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that you do not have control over the page you are trying to manipulate, you will have to work with the HTML as it is.  In this case, providing you do have control over the browser you are using (are you doing this from the console?), you can use `document.querySelector`: [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

So, in your specific case, you'd want to do

```js
document.querySelector('[value="Add"]').click()
```

Or, to make things more specific, you could do

```js
document.querySelector('#UserManagebutton1 input[value="Add"]').click()
```

Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xonev/V6SQ2/

Comment: I see how he got it working he made it more specific in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<input type="button" id="Add" value="Add" class="inputbutton">
document.getElementById('Add').click();
```

Note you need `id="Add"` in order to get it using `getElementById('Add')`

Comment: Im getting the error for some reason below `TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null`

Comment: @sonicboom Make sure you use `getElementById` AFTER loading the button to the DOM (e.g. use it in a script just before `</body>`)

Comment: @sonicboom If you can't change the code, how do you plan to solve it?

Comment: So there is no way to click on a value? Damn.

Answer (score 1):

You have no unique identifiers for your buttons. Make an ID that is the same as the value.

```
<td valign="top" id="UserManagebutton1">
  <input type="button" id="Add" value="Add" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" id="Delete" value="Delete" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" id="Import" value="Import" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" id="Export" value="Export" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" id="Change" value="Change Status" class="inputbutton">
  <input type="button" id="Purge" value="Purge AD Users" class="inputbutton">
</td>
```

Use this, then your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have set the value of the button to `Add` which simply means that the text that will appear on the button is `Add`. Value, as an attribute sets the text of that element.

If you want to access that element by id, you need to specify an `id` attribute for it, like this:

```
<input id="Add" class="inputbutton" type="button" value="Add">
```

And to access the button you could simply use the code that you have used in your post:

```
document.getElementById('Add').click();
```

Also, if you do not want to modify your current code, you could simply use another javascript selector to get that specific element, such as:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('inputbutton')[0].click();
```

Moreover, if you want to add click event listeners for the other elements, as you do for the `Add` button, you could do some `Event Delegation` which is great to manage performance:

```
// Bind the event listener to the top most element that contains your event targets
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // Get target of the event
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    switch(target.value) {
      case('Add'):
        alert('Add button clicked!');
        break;
      ...
      // Add cases for the other buttons as well
    }
});
```

Here is a simpler version that only listens for clicks on the `Add` button:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (target.value == 'Add') {
        alert('You clicked?');
    }
});
```

Comment: I cant edit my code but im getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` using the bottom code you supplied.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try it out and let me know if it works! It should work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any JS libraries, try:

`document.getElementsByName('Add')[0].click()`

**UPDATED - correction below**

Since the buttons don't have `name` attributes (thanks @Rocket Hazmat) and since you cannot change the HTML, you can try this instead:

`document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();`

// [0] for add button,
// [1] for Delete button,
// etc.

Comment: The button doesn't have a `name` attribute.

Comment: Im getting the error for some reason below `TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null`

Comment: @sonicboom as @Rocket Hazmat pointed out, the buttons don't have `name` attributes. you can either add them, or add Ids and use @Oriol's answer above

Comment: I tried using your new code @blurfus but its not working. same as the guy below.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('inputbutton')[0].click();
TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined
message: "Cannot call method 'click' of undefined"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
`

Comment: the tag name is not `inputbutton` the tag name is input (guy above was looking at `getElementsByClassName('inputbutton')`

Comment: that's because you have not instructed the button click to do anything... :)

Comment: how can i instruct it to click?

Comment: the button itself is not set to do anything onclick and you cannot modify the code so I am not sure what you need to accomplish...

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this? Cause i can click it on this webpage and it opens a menu.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... the code (by itself, as posted above) does not do anything.  On a webpage, there may be other scripts that assign an action to it (after rendering) but I wouldn't know what those are (since this is the first time you mention said web page)

Comment: The guy above solved it. `document.querySelector('#UserManagebutton1 input[value="Add"]').click()`

Comment: Anyhoo, if you are still interested in assigning an action to the buttons, I created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Yhy/12/